# i can't access to an span with parent class name

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I try this code But It's Return NULL object!

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
include_once ('Scraper.php');
$scraper = new Scraper();
$pageUrl = 'https://www.zara.com/tr/en/wrap-blouse-with-bow-p04437059.html?v1=6022035&v2=943001';
$pageHtmlContent = $scraper->curl($pageUrl);
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($pageHtmlContent);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$prise= $xpath->evaluate('(//div[@class=\'._product-price\'])');
var_dump($prise);
?>
```

I use selectorGadget to Make XPATH Address .

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry, can't add comment, not enaugh reputation :(.*

You'r xpath is incorect, I can't find anything in given url. Please provide what you wish to find.

**Edit to comment**

To find exact div (as I tried, there is only 1 div with certains class in given url), use this xpath `(//*[contains(@class,'_product-price')])`. If you need the price that is within that div, use this xpath `(//*[contains(@class,'_product-price')]/span)`. If there will be more then 1 xpath, use this `(//*[contains(@class,'_product-price')]/span)[i]` where `i` is within loop over DOM elements.

e.g.

```
dom_elements = [get_dom_elements]
store_value = []
i = 1
while i < len(dom_elements):
    xpath = '(//*[contains(@class,'_product-price')]/span)[i]'
    store_value.append(some_function_for_getting_value_of_dom(xpath))
    i += 1
```

Comment: i need to access to content of A div By "._product-price" class name .

Comment: p.s. my answer is in Python, but the same way you can implement in PHP :)